# Identify missing fender part

Tags: repair, parts, replacement, fenders, identify-this-bike

Let's play "identify the missing part"!

While riding, something which holds the fender to the frame between the chainstays and just behind the bottom bracket fell off:
[image: Fender with missing part highlighted]

Please help me make my bike stop making horrible rattling noises.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need

1. Leather washers in between the metal fender and frame.
2. a washer and locking nut to secure the fixing bolt.

For detailed instructions on metal fender install see the detailed [Velo Oranges fender manual](http://support.velo-orange.com/pdf/Fender.pdf).

[image: Annotated]

Comment: It's been about 30 years since I last saw a leather washer.  If a washer is needed, rubber or plastic will work fine, and plain old steel in a pinch.

Comment: I just installed new metal fenders complete with leather washers last month. They still seem to be in use by metal fender manufacturers and recommended to reduce likelihood of stress fractures.  [VeloOrange sells packs of 6](http://store.velo-orange.com/index.php/accessories/fenders/fender-hardware/leather-washers-for-mounting-fenders.html) for about $6.

Answer (score 2):

It looks to me like you just lost the nut.  A stainless steel nut and washer or a stainless steel nylock nut would work best for this application.  These options would help prevent the nut from coming loose and falling off again.  You could also try using threadlock to help secure the nut as well.